# OpenEXR animations and Adobe Premiere Pro?

Tags: animation, video, .exr

I'm experimenting with rendering my Blender animations as OpenEXR MultiLayer image sequences (this video piqued my interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UjJqwwMJc8). The problem is that I do my video editing with Adobe Premiere Pro and Premiere imports the OpenEXR images as black frames; there's nothing I can do with them.

Meanwhile, I installed an addon called "Exr-IO" which allows Adobe Photoshop to read these OpenEXR files, and it does an excellent job, so I'm reasonably confident that the OpenEXR files Blender rendered are fine. Unfortunately, I cannot find an addon that will allow Premiere to do the same.

Anybody else have any luck with OpenEXR and Premiere Pro? or another video editor? Thanks. Blender 3.0, Premiere Pro 22.1.2, Windows 11

Comment: Try the free version of Blackmagic Da Vinci Resolve as shown in the video. I use it all the time, and personally, it's a lovely piece of software. It's like the Blender of Video Editing softwares. So good that it competes with paid softwares like Adobe, and yet, completely free!

Comment: @Hrishav Saha, thank you!